# Logout action is being dispatched from component but not a reducer and not effect called

Tags: angular, angular7, ngrx

I have a topbar component in an Angular application where an Action is dispatched for logout

```
this.store.dispatch(new Logout());
```

now this supposed to call Reducer which will return initial state

```
export const initialAuthState: AuthState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    authToken: undefined,
    user: undefined,
    isUserLoaded: false
};
```

```
  case AuthActionTypes.Logout:
            return initialAuthState;
```

- and trigger Effect to clear local storage and session and redirect user to login screen like below.

```
 @Effect({dispatch: false})
    logout$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<Logout>(AuthActionTypes.Logout),
        tap(() => {
            sessionStorage.clear();
            localStorage.clear();
            
            if(this.returnUrl){
                window.location.href = "/user-auth/sign-in?returnUrl="+this.returnUrl;
            }else{
                window.location.href = "/user-auth/sign-in";
            }
            
        })
    );
```

but after clicking on Logout button on UI, the Action is dispatched (I put debugger and confirmed that it is hit), and in Redux DevTool I am not able to see any Logout action log.

- I checked app.Module.ts to verify that Effect and Reducer is mentioned there

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        // PartialsModule,
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
        OverlayModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({ stateKey: "router" }),
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
        AuthUserModule.forRoot(),
        NgbModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        InlineSVGModule.forRoot(),
```

- here is where Reducer and meta reducer is written, attached image for this
- and since my Auth module is feature module, here is Auth user module.ts file code

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        TranslateModule.forChild(),         
        StoreModule.forFeature('auth', authReducer),
        EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects]),
        DxValidatorModule,
        DxFormModule,
        DxButtonModule,
        FormsModule,
        DxLoadIndicatorModule
    ],
```

- login is working from start, but when I click for logout, nothing happens

I tried by validating versions of my project dependencies here is the version list

```json
{
    "name": "virtualasset-angular",
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --port 4300 --poll 200",
        "start-no-poll": "ng serve --port 4300 ",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "csharp-to-typescript": "gulp csharp-to-typescript",
        "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/virtualasset/stats.json",
        "build": "node --max_old_space_size=12288 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod   --extract-css=false",
        "build-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=12288 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json  --extract-css=false"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "360-image-viewer": "^1.0.1",
        "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.7",
        "@agm/js-marker-clusterer": "1.1.0",
        "@angular/animations": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/cdk": "7.3.3",
        "@angular/common": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/compiler": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/core": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/forms": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/http": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/router": "7.2.7",
        "@auth0/angular-jwt": "5.0.2",
        "@devexpress/analytics-core": "21.2.3",
        "@microsoft/signalr": "5.0.10",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.4",
        "@ngrx/effects": "7.3.0",
        "@ngrx/entity": "7.3.0",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "7.3.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "7.3.0",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "7.3.0",
        "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "3.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1",
        "@types/jspdf": "1.3.1",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.122",
        "@types/nodemailer": "6.2.2",
        "@types/numeral": "0.0.26",
        "acorn": "8.5.0",
        "body-parser": "1.19.0",
        "canvas-fit": "1.5.0",
        "chart.js": "2.7.3",
        "chartist": "0.11.0",
        "core-js": "2.6.5",
        "dashboard-extensions": "git+https://git@github.com/DevExpress/dashboard-extensions.git",
        "devexpress-dashboard": "21.2.3",
        "devexpress-dashboard-angular": "21.2.3",
        "devexpress-diagram": "2.0.38",
        "devexpress-gantt": "3.0.14",
        "devexpress-reporting-angular": "21.2.3",
        "devexpress-richedit": "21.2.3",
        "devextreme": "21.2.3",
        "devextreme-angular": "21.2.3",
        "exceljs": "4.2.1",
        "fast-xml-parser": "4.0.7",
        "file-saver": "2.0.2",
        "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
        "highlight.js": "9.15.6",
        "html2canvas": "1.0.0-rc.5",
        "jquery": "3.4.1",
        "jspdf": "1.5.3",
        "lodash": "4.17.11",
        "moment": "2.29.1",
        "ng-click-outside": "4.0.0",
        "leaflet": "1.7.1",
        "ng-inline-svg": "8.6.0",
        "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^4.0.5",
        "ng-qrcode": "4.2.0",
        "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.4",
        "ngx-color-picker": "8.1.0",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "2.2.0",
        "ngx-doc-viewer": "2.0.4",
        "ngx-moment": "5.0.0",
        "rxjs": "6.3.3",
        "save": "2.4.0",
        "sweetalert2": "10.15.5",
        "tslib": "1.9.0",
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
        "xlsx": "0.14.3",
        "zone.js": "0.8.26",
        "panolens": "0.12.1",
        "openseadragon": "2.4.2",
        "object-path": "0.11.4",
        "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
        "photo-sphere-viewer": "4.2.1"
    },
    "browser": {
        "fs": true,
        "path": true,
        "os": false
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.9",
        "@angular/cli": "7.3.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.7",
        "@angular/language-service": "7.2.7",
        "@ngrx/schematics": "7.3.0",
        "@schematics/angular": "7.3.10",
        "@types/chartist": "0.9.43",
        "@types/googlemaps": "3.43.3",
        "@types/highlight.js": "9.12.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "8.9.4",
        "@types/object-path": "0.9.29",
        "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
        "gulp": "4.0.2",
        "gulp-chmod": "3.0.0",
        "gulp-clean": "0.4.0",
        "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
        "gulp-insert": "0.5.0",
        "gulp-merge": "0.1.1",
        "gulp-typescript-cs-poco": "1.12.0",
        "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
        "karma": "4.0.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.5",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
        "node-sass": "4.14.1",
        "protractor": "5.4.0",
        "require-dir": "1.2.0",
        "ts-node": "7.0.0",
        "tslint": "5.11.0",
        "typescript": "3.2.2",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.7.0"
    }
}
```

- also I checked by comparing my old working project with same code, (compared code line by line in DifferentChecker tool) all same

Answer (score 0):

1- `dispatch` takes an `action` as a parameter.

Try: `this.store.dispatch(AuthActionTypes.Logout);`

Instead of: `this.store.dispatch(new Logout());`

2- `ofType` takes an `action`. When creating effect use:

```
ofType(AuthActionTypes.Logout),
```

3- What errors have you in the `console` of browser devTool?

UPDATE:
4- Define logout action as flowing:

```
import { createAction } from "@ngrx/store";

export const logout  = createAction('[useAuth] Logout');
```

Comment: Hi @jamil thanks for replying. Really appreciate it. To answer your question there is no console error logged. That is the reason I am totally confused.

Comment: Actually it's har to find the problem without some input, or project in https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: while dispatching Action from Component dispatch() method takes Action as you said. 
when i will pass AuthActionTypes.Logout in dispatch method, Compiler will get mad at me 
since AuthActionTypes is Enum not an Action Type

Comment: I updated the answer with the way we define the actions, try it and let me know if there's problem.

Comment: not working still...